# How to make a single form that will send data to multiple table in Microsoft SQL server ? ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have created one to one relationship between these two table called Model.User and Model.Company in SQL server by using Model Migration in ASP.net core MVC.  I do not know how to insert data to these two table  using this single View.User

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "User ID")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string UserID { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [MinLength(6, ErrorMessage = "Minimum 6 characters required")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}



public class Company
{
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    [Display(Name = "Company ID")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Company number required")]
    public string CompanyID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Company name required")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company Address")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Company address required")]
    public string CompanyAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Users/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("UserID,UserName,PhoneNumber,Password,CompanyID,CompanyName,CompanyAddress")] User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(user);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: if you show us the code you're trying to do it would be helpful understanding your problem also the controller code and the classes you've created.

Answer (score 0):

first of all create a custom model which will contains both model. Like

```
public class mainModel
{
   public User userModel{get; set;}
   public Company companyModel{get; set;}
}
```

and after that declare this model in your view so you will be able to use both model using mainModel in your view.